# PHP mail function not sending. Need another set of eyes

Tags: php, email, if-statement

```
<?php
    session_start();

    $returnURL = $_POST["pageURL"].'#confirmation';

    if (empty($_POST["phone"]) || empty($_POST["email"]) || empty($_POST["name"])  || empty($_POST["address"]) ) {

    $_SESSION["confirmation"] = "empty";
    header('Location: '.$returnURL);
    exit;

    } else {

    $to = 'email@email.com';
    $headers = 'From: ' . $_POST["name"] . '<' . $_POST["email"] . '>';
    $subject = 'Email from your landing page';          
    $message = (
    "You have received a inquiry from your landing page! \n\n Name: " . $_POST["name"] . " 
    \n Email: " . $_POST["email"] . "
    \n Phone Number: " . $_POST["phone"] .  "
    \n Mailing Address: " . $_POST["address"] .  "
    \n Message: " . $_POST["message"]
    );

    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

    $_SESSION["confirmation"] = 'yes';
    header('Location: '.$returnURL);
    exit;
    }
?>
```

Comment: Are you receiving an error? Or just not receiving the email?

Comment: Do you have `sendmail` or a similar package installed?

Comment: I've not even received the question.

Comment: I think OP has left us in limbo.

Answer (score 0):

Please see the documentation of the [`mail`](http://de.php.net/mail) function, it returns a value. Check it and report that back. Also disable the redirect while debugging:

```
$result = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
var_dump($result);
exit;
```

Comment: Tried this out and it returned bool(false)

Comment: Documentation says: *"Returns TRUE if the mail was successfully accepted for delivery, FALSE otherwise."* Ergo: Your mail was not accepted for delivery. Contact your hoster support and ask if it is possible to send emails via PHP or if you need to do some settings first. Additionally you might want to dump to, subject, message and headers and pass that information to your technical support, too.

Comment: This might be the problem actually. I will check on that.

Answer (score 0):

Headers can be extremely finicky. Try adding new lines at the end of the From.

```
$headers = 'From: ' . $_POST["name"] . '<' . $_POST["email"] . ">\r\n";
```